# Ember model data not shown in template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a problem displaying model data inside the template. Here's my code:

1. /routes/index.js

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.find('video');
    }
});
```

2. /adapters/application.js

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    defaultSerializer: 'JSONSerializer'
});
```

3. /serializers/application.js

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({});
```

4. /templates/index.hbs

```js
{{#each video in model}}
    <p>{{video.title}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

however the data is not shown. I have checked the response from the server and it's a valid jsonapi.org format response. I tested by returning an `Ember.Object` from `/router/index.js:model()` and the data renders just fine. I'm confused why ember can't access the data from the store when I have specified to use `JSONSerializer` but renders when data returns as an array of objects. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
If I log `{{log model}}` in template, I get the following output:

`Class {store: Class, isLoaded: true, manager: Class, isUpdating: false, __ember1448322947671: null…}`

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @torazaburo no errors at all.

Comment: Ember versions? Can you try `this.store.query`?

Comment: @torazaburo I have just fixed this, was in the middle of posting an answer. The problem was I used `JSONSerializer` instead of `JSONAPISerializer`

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. Looks like Ember changed the serializer name, it should be `JSONAPISerializer` instead of `JSONSerializer`

Comment: These are two separate serializers, now both supported by Ember.js